# Check if all elements in list follow 2 conditions

Tags: python, list

I have this code here:

```py
if all([condition for x in lis]) and all([condition for y in lis]):
   return True
```

My code checks if all elements in a list follow two conditions,
would there be a more readable/pythonic way to write this?

Comment: Why not `if all( condition1 and condition2 for x in lis ):`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this one.

```
if all([condition1 and condition2 for x in lis]):
   return True
```

This way is faster and memory efficient.